# How to get an array of values of node ids from entity reference field with EntityMetadataWrappers

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using a EntityMetadataWrapper on a profile2 entity. One of the fields is a multi-value entity reference field to nodes.  I want to simple get the node ids as an array, so I can do a quick in_array() to see if a value already exists.

I can't seem to find how to easily do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
$ids = $wrapper->field_foo->raw();
```

And if you want an array of entities instead:

```
$entities = $wrapper->field_foo->value();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to get my arms around entity wrappers.